# "__rvm_do_with_env_before" and "__rvm_after_cd" when doing "cd"

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal, rvm

I recently uninstalled RVM (mostly I think). When I "`cd`" in the terminal I get:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro% cd
__rvm_do_with_env_before:source:5: no such file or directory: /Users/adam/.rvm/scripts/initialize
__rvm_after_cd:source:5: no such file or directory: /Users/adam/.rvm/scripts/hook
```

How do I fix this? I'm guessing it's because I didn't completely uninstall RVM. What steps do I have left to do after I `rvm implode`

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

it should be enough to reopen your terminal, in rare cases relogin/restart is needed.

Comment: btw - I tried re-assert the profile (source ~/.zshrc) thinking that it would be equivalent of starting a new terminal window.  did not work for me :( so I had to stick to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

1. gedit .zshrc or  .bash_profile or other depending of your shell
2. remove anything present like
   PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" 
   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
   source /home/rahul/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
   or other related to rvm.

after that close all terminal sessions then reopen it again  and try "cd" any directory, it may resolved by now!

Comment: Allow though I pretty sure your answer, solves the issue. Please provide a more ellaborate explanation as to why the solution will work :)